# Sort FASTA file according to length of sequences

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I am working with a genome sequence of a bird and I have run the genome through RepeatMasker. I want to find the longest sequences in each class of repeats. How do I list my repeats according to the length of the sequences?

```
>rnd-4_family-127#LTR/ERV1
GTTGCCTTTTTCCCAACCTGGAAATGAAAC[...]
>rnd-4_family-1329#Unknown
TCTATCACTTCGGCCCGCGCCAGGAGTGG [...]
```

the `>` indicates a new seq  and I want something like

```
>rnd-4_family-127#LTR/ERV1
112
```

I want the length of each sequence like this and then save it in some file. so that I can then sort this file according to the length of each sequence (e.g. order of increasing length)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Say a file with 10 (shortened) lines as input and the expected output. Do you want to search each line by character length?

Comment: Any specific reason to use Java for this? It’s not the most suitable language for these kinds of task and, although some people use it routinely, it’s very niche in bioinformatics (outside of large projects such as GATK & IGV).

Comment: >rnd-4_family-127#LTR/ERV1
GTTGCCTTTTTCCCAACCTGGAAATGAAAC[...]

>rnd-4_family-1329#Unknown 
TCTATCACTTCGGCCCGCGCCAGGAGTGG [...]

the '>' indicates a new seq

and I want something like 
>nd-4_family-127#LTR/ERV1
new line: 112
I want the lenght of each sequence like this and then save it in some file? So that I can then sort this file according to the lenght of each sequence (e.g. order of increasing lenght)

awk '/^>/{if (l!="") print l; print; l=0; next}{l+=length($0)}END{print l}' fasta.file

I found this code and I think it does the job of defining the length of each sequence

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm a masters student and I unfortunately dont have much knowledge of programming languages yet.. so for now I'm only using bash commands

Comment: Don't put multiline code into a comment. It becomes virtually unreadable, as you probably can see for yourself.

Comment: You could create a file, where each line contains three fields: The length of a sequence, the name of the sequence, and the sequence itself.  Then sort the file numerically by its length.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. For example, use `seqkit` `fx2tab`/`tab2fx` to convert fasta to tab-delimited format, write the lengths of sequences, then use `sort` to sort by sequence length, and finally convert back to `fasta`:

```
 seqkit fx2tab --length in.fa | sort -t $'\t' -k4,4n | seqkit tab2fx > out.fa
```

Note that `seqkit` suite of tools can be easily installed, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html), specifically `miniconda`, like so:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqkit seqkit
```

Example:

input:

```
>seq1 with blanks
ACGT ACGT ACGT
>seq2 with newlines
ACGT

ACGT

>seq3 without blanks or newlines
ACGT
```

output:

```
>seq3 without blanks or newlines
ACGT
>seq2 with newlines
ACGTACGT
>seq1 with blanks
ACGT ACGT ACGT
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, assuming that there are only two alternating types of lines in the file: the name (starting with `>`) and the sequence. Every sequence must be a single line only and come directly after the name:

```
awk '
/^>/{name=$0;next}
{print length($0), name, $0}
' file.fasta | sort -n
```

If the sequence can be split across multiple lines, it becomes a bit trickier, but still managable:

```
awk '
/^>/&&name{print len,name;len=0}
/^>/{name=$0;next}
{len+=length($0)}
END{print len,name}
' file.fasta | sort -n
```

Alternatively, if all names are unique:

```
awk '
/^>/{name=$0;next}
{a[name]+=length($0)}
END{for(name in a){print a[name], name}}
' file.fasta | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How do I list my repeats according to the length of the sequences? ..."*

Use a *class* to contain the data.

```java
class Sequence {
    String name, s;

    Sequence(String name, String s) {
        this.name = name;
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%s, %s".formatted(s.length(), name);
    }
}
```

Generate a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*.

```java
List<Sequence> l = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("sequences.txt"))) {
    String s;
    while (in.hasNextLine())
        if ((s = in.nextLine()).startsWith(">"))
            l.add(new Sequence(s, in.nextLine()));
}
```

Then, sort the *List*.

```java
l.sort((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.s.length(), a.s.length()));
```

Output

```
30, >rnd-4_family-127#LTR/ERV1
29, >rnd-4_family-1329#Unknown
```